# Where does the de-biased model get trained in Watson OpenScale?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-openscale

Does the model get trained in Watson Machine Learning, some other 3rd party engines or micro services in OpenScale?

After the model is trained, where does it get served? Can I inspect/modify the model?

Answer (score 0):

The model is trained in the Fairness micro-service of the IBM AI OpenScale and is not deployed anywhere. It is used to de-bias the output of the user's model and as and when required. The model is not available for users to use as it is not a replica of the user's model.

Comment: But there's a scoring ending point in the UI. What's that for?